# How to programmatically retrieve product version of AEM/CQ5

Tags: aem

AEM 5.6.1.

I have a package. I'd like to be able to 'sniff' the version of AEM a user/administraor is using when attempting to install the package.

The version is available in the front-end via Tools -> Web Console -> Main -> Product Information

I appreciate I could parse the above page and extract but surely there's a more elegant way to do it?

I've looked through Adobe docs on Packages: (I would post links but SO complaining I've not got enough reputation) And had a good hunt around SO.

The closest I've come is through this doc: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/programmatically-accessing-cq-content-using.html and assuming that the details found in CRX @ /etc/packages/day:

- cq5
- cq560
- cq561

represent a typical install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current versions of AEM provide this info is via the `ProductInfoService` described at [1], which can return a number of `ProductInfo` objects.

This is already available in 5.6.1, also via the OSGi console at `/system/console/status-productinfo` .

[1] https://docs.adobe.com/docs/fr/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/granite/license/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

To pro-grammatically retrieve the product version of any running AEM instance can be done by the following code snippet.

```
@Reference 
private ProductInfoProvider productInfo;

String version = productInfo.getProductInfo().getShortVersion();
```

First we need to inject the **ProductInfoProvider** service or define the references of **ProductInfoProvider** into your service and use following functions calls to get the version information as 
    **productInfo.getProductInfo().getShortVersion();**

Answer (score 0):

The product information is stored on the node "/libs/cq/core/productinfo" , you can read the information from those nodes.

You don't specify if you'll have repository access while the package is being installed. In case you want the data as JSON over HTTP just hit the path with ".json" extension

**Source :** Checked the network requests made by the [aem developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aem-developer/hgjhcngmldfpgpakbnffnbnmcmohfmfc) chrome plugin

Comment: Thanks for reply @sharath, also useful. Particularly the plugin link :)

Answer (score 0):

For AEM 6.5

```
com.adobe.granite.license.ProductInfoProvider; 
com.adobe.granite.license.ProductInfo;

@OSGiService
private ProductInfoProvider productInfoProvider;

ProductInfo productInfo = productInfoProvider.getProductInfo(); 
productInfo.getVerion().toString(); //6.5.13.0
productInfo.getShortVersion(); //6.5
```

Thanks